# Magento SQLSTATE[42000] error while trying to synchronize media storage to database

Tags: mysql, magento, magento-1.9

In magento I've changed the media storage settings from File System to Database and clicked Synchronize. It isn't successful and I'm getting the following error message:

> An error has occured while syncronizing media storages. One or more media files failed to be synchronized during the media storages syncronization process.

**Here is the exception.log file results:**

```
2014-12-30T05:18:35+00:00 ERR (3):
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC or     ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.' in /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:82
Stack trace:
#0 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(82): PDOStatement->execute()
#1 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(108): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_executeWithBinding(Array)
#2 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#3 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#4 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#5 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#6 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1934): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#7 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/File/Storage/Database.php(206): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertOnDuplicate('core_file_stora...', Array, Array)
#8 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Storage/Database.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_File_Storage_Database->saveFile(Array)
#9 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Storage.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage_Database->importFiles(Array)
#10 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php(86): Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage->synchronize(Array)
#11 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_Config_System_StorageController->synchronizeAction()
#12 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('synchronize')
#13 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/example/public_html/dev/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}

Next exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1118 Row size too large (> 8126). Changing some columns to TEXT or BLOB or using ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC     or ROW_FORMAT=COMPRESSED may help. In current row format, BLOB prefix of 768 bytes is stored inline.' in /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php:84
Stack trace:
#0 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(108): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_executeWithBinding(Array)
#1 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Zend/Db/Statement.php(291): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(480): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#4 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(428): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#5 /home/example/public_html/dev/lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(1934): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `co...', Array)
#6 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Resource/File/Storage/Database.php(206): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertOnDuplicate('core_file_stora...', Array, Array)
#7 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Storage/Database.php(213): Mage_Core_Model_Resource_File_Storage_Database->saveFile(Array)
#8 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/File/Storage.php(205): Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage_Database->importFiles(Array)
#9 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/System/Config/System/StorageController.php(86): Mage_Core_Model_File_Storage->synchronize(Array)
#10 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_System_Config_System_StorageController->synchronizeAction()
#11 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('synchronize')
#12 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#13 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#14 /home/example/public_html/dev/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#15 /home/example/public_html/dev/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#16 {main}
```

**Her is my MYSQL my.cnf file:**

```
[mysqld]
innodb_file_per_table=1
local-infile=0
open_files_limit=3334
max_allowed_packet=268435456
innodb_buffer_pool_size=134217728

# Custom
query_cache_type = 1
query_cache_size = 64M
query_cache_limit = 2M
thread_cache_size = 32
join_buffer_size = 8M
tmp_table_size = 256M
key_buffer = 32M
innodb_autoextend_increment = 512
max_heap_table_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 2M
read_rnd_buffer_size = 16M
bulk_insert_buffer_size = 64M
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 128M
myisam_max_sort_file_size = 10G
myisam_repair_threads = 1
```

While trying to figure it out I read it can be due to a large amount of attributes setup in magento, but I only have 64, and not many of those are set to 'Used in Product Listing'.

I can't disable the 'Flat Catalog Products' setting as I will have over 30,000+ products in this store.

I have also checked that the media folder is writable.

Answer (score 1):

Seems obvious what is happening. The column type in the database for media does not support the string size you are inserting. It's however unsure whether this problem is caused by the filename length or the image size.

Image size:

When inserting media as database rows, the images are encoded to strings. These strings are then entered into a database column. The larger the images get the longer the strings will become, as each pixel information will be stored. So you probably use images that are too large. The SQL error you are getting provides a solution for your issue, to change the column type in the database to BLOB. Doing this manually might solve your issue, but it might not be compatible with magento up- or downgrades.

After some googling it seems column "content" is blob, so this should not be the issue.

Filename size:

There might also be a field that stores the filename, if this column has a length limit you will also get this error. Mostly such columns are 255 in length. Please verify there are no images inserted into the database with filenames that are too long.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I only have 2 test products in the database at the moment, I removed both their images and re-uploaded a 500px*500px image with a short filename(test.jpg). The error is still occuring.

Comment: And I have the default magento theme still, so I wouldn't think any of those default images would be the problem.